# Astroquery is returning very different semi major axis compared to one in https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sats/elem/

Tags: jpl-horizons, jpl

```
sim_start_date = "2000-01-01.5"     
sim_duration = 2 * 365               
time = Time(sim_start_date).jd

obj = Horizons(id=iMoon, location="@sun", epochs=time , id_type='id')
el = obj.elements()
print ('Semi Major Axis of Object is',el['a'])
print ('Eccentricity of Object is',el['e'])
print ('Inclination of Object is',el['incl'])
```

I am running these codes to get dataset of various moons of the planets-Earth, Mars, Jupiter etc. However, semi major axis returned by the above function in AU are very different from the dataset in https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sats/elem/

I am getting following semi major axis for Io using astroquery function but this is significantly different from one in https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sats/elem/

```
  Io (501) 2451544.500005787 ... 17.19251538391498 9502.78235638569
Semi Major Axis of Object is         a        
        AU       
-----------------
8.780142753821996
```

(this is much higher than the one obtained from jpl horizon table: 421800 km or 0.0027 AU)

```
Eccentricity of Object is         e         
       ---        
------------------
0.9581134232050015
Inclination of Object is        incl      
       deg       
-----------------
8.778366263433657
```

Dataset in https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sats/elem/

```
Jupiter Io  501 JUP365  Laplace 2000-01-01.5    421800. 0.004   49.1    330.9   0.0 0.0 1.762732    1.333   0.000   268.1   64.5    0.0 23
```

Comment: This is off topic. I think this question would be better at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this is a better place for it than codereview.  It's about astronomy software, not code.  It's highly unlikely codereview users would be familiar with these libs.

Comment: What would it have said for other moons of Jupiter? If the figures are close to the same as those for Io, you are measuring distance relative to something other than the planet Jupiter. You may need to put planet's motion into the program.